# Node.js put records to Kinesis with infinite retry strategy.

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, amazon-web-services

My application is really easy. It's going to add 500 records at a time to AWS Kinesis and if there's an error occur I'll just add that back to the queue and it's going to be retry. It's going well but I feel like there's a bug somewhere that I don't see.

```
'use strict';

const _ = require('lodash');
const moment = require('moment');

const config = require('../config');
const logger = require('../logger');
const numbers = require('../helpers/numbers');

const streamName = config.kinesis.streamName;

let records = [];
module.exports = (kinesis) => {
  let sendRecords = () => {
    let payloadRecords = {
      Records: records,
      StreamName: streamName
    };

    if (records.length >= 500) {
      const pushingToKinesis = records.splice(0, 500);
      payloadRecords.Records = pushingToKinesis;
    } else {
      records = []
    }

    kinesis.putRecords(payloadRecords, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        logger.error(err);
      }

      const failedRecord = _.get(data, 'FailedRecordCount', 0);

      if (failedRecord > 0) {

        logger.warn(`There are ${data.FailedRecordCount} failed`);

        data.Records.forEach((record, index) => {
          if (_.has(record, 'ErrorCode') || _.has(record, 'ErrorMessage')) {
            logger.debug(record);
            logger.debug(payloadRecords.Records[index]);

            records.push(payloadRecords.Records[index]);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };

  let putRecord = (record) => {
    let payload = {
      Data: JSON.stringify(record),
      PartitionKey: String(numbers.random() * 100000)
    };
    records.push(payload);

    if (records.length >= config.kinesis.maxRecords) {
      sendRecords();
    }
  };

  return {
    putRecord: putRecord,
    recordCount: () => {
      return records.length;
    },
    clearRecord: () => {
      records = [];
    },
    init: () => {
      setInterval(() => {
        if (!_.isEmpty(records)) { 
          sendRecords();
        }
      }, 200);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: *"I feel like there's a bug somewhere I don't see."* - Do you mean that you're worried about overlooked issues or are you actually getting bad data from this script?

Comment: Yes. I'm worried that I might have overlooked something. Am I in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no obvious bug but;

- You are defining functions both within the `return` structure and outside of it, which makes it hard to read/parse, just keep it clean and define everything outside of it
- You are sending records in a function called `putRecord`, that is not good.
- `500` should probably be a constant retrieved with `config`, same thing for `200`
- Using `numbers.random()` sounds like a terrible idea, you should use a library that generates GUID's (https://www.npmjs.com/package/guid)
- Why assign `config.kinesis.streamName` to `streamName`, just assign it straight in the structure. It is one less line of code, and the reader does not have to wonder where it comes from
- I would have re-ordered the 500 check and the assignment:

  ```
  records  = records.splice(0, 500);

  let payloadRecords = {
    Records: records,
    StreamName: streamName
  };
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  let payloadRecords = {
    Records: records,
   StreamName: streamName
  };

  if (records.length >= 500) {
    const pushingToKinesis = records.splice(0, 500);
    payloadRecords.Records = pushingToKinesis;
  } else {
    records = []
  }
  ```

  personally I would even go for

  ```
  //Make sure we never send more than 500 records, splice keeps the rest in records
  let payloadRecords = {
    Records: records.splice(0, 500),
    StreamName: streamName
  };
  ```

Finally, I am not a big fan of perpetually re-sending the data. If the data gets rejected because of data-content, then at some point if you reach 500 entries that will never be stored, your pipe will filled with junk and you will stop transmitting store-able data.

Comment: Thanks for this. It really is helpful. Right now, I have no way of checking bad data because Kinesis only returns two things; ProvisionThroughPut and InternalFailure and they can be thrown anytime according to AWS documentation.

Comment: You could keep track of the re-tries in a separate structure (GUID/retrycount), and remove from the queue after 10 tries.